# HTML5 Video player start playing from wrong time

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I want to control the video to start playing from the exact time value as given in the JS code below.

But the player does not do as expect.
For example, if I do `vid.currentTime = 1.2`, the player will start from 00:00 sec. Or if I do 22, the player will start from timeline 00:21 sec

I am not sure it is because not possible to get the accurate timeline from mp4 (codec challenge)?

Thanks!

```js
var vid = document.getElementById("video1");
vid.currentTime = 2;
vid.play();
```

```html
<video id="video1" width="320" height="240">
     <source src="http://example.com/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Comment: I've replicated in similar conditions your code in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/CrisMVP3200/sua0xp9n/), and at least for me, the issue you specified is not present (I added the controls property just to display the actual time). Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should wait for the browser to load the metadata and then trigger the event on meta data loading. Let say if you want to start the video 21 seconds onward:

```
document.getElementById('video1').addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function(){
 this.currentTime = 21;
}, false);
```

Comment: I dont think this is the cause. because the player is already playing content before I click buttons to trigger the currentTime set.

Comment: yes because due to vid.play(); it couldn't interpret the line vid.currentTime as the metadata is not loaded and play the video. So put this.play(); after this.currentTime in metadata event listener. I hope it will work .